# Insert r inline code in abstract with rticles journal template

Tags: r, r-markdown, journal

I am using a `r-markdown rticles` journal template to prepare a manuscript. Almost all `rticles` templates place the abstract in the YAML header section. I am not able to insert inline r code to the abstract in YAML. I could move the abstract to the text section to insert inline `r` code. However, the final format would also change. In biomedical field, abstracts often include some numbers from data. What is the best way to add `r` inline code to the abstract with a `rticles` journal template? Thanks

**Edit:** I have just realized that `r` code for analysis can be placed before the YAML header section. This will solve my problem. Here is a shorten version using Elsevier Journal template:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
n <- length(mtcars$mpg)
```

---
title: Short Paper
author:
  - name: Alice Anonymous
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliation: Some Institute of Technology
    footnote: Corresponding Author
address:
  - code: Some Institute of Technology
    address: Department, Street, City, State, Zip
abstract: |
   There are `r n` observations.   
journal: "An awesome journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
bibliography: mybibfile.bib
csl: elsevier-harvard.csl
output: rticles::elsevier_article
---
````

However, the journal template in the YAML header is no longer working. Now, I am back to where I started.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far?